# JavaScript console.log from within a function

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, logging, console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.serializeJSON.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit-button").click(function(e)
{
  var username = JSON.serialize($('#username').val().toLowerCase());
  console.log($('#username').val());


});
});
</script>
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="title">Login Form</div>
  <div class="form-fields">
  <form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required></input>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="submit-button"></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to log the username variable after serializing it but console.log is not printing anything from within the function. What is the best way to debug in this type of situation.

Comment: can you show the html?

Comment: one reason for not printing is that code never gets to console.log line and it errors out before it.  Did you try to console.log before the username field evaluation to see if the submit button event fires?

Comment: method `serializeJSON` seems suspicious, strings in js don't have method with this name

Comment: add 'Debugger;' to the .click function to see if it is getting in the method.

Comment: `toLowerCaser()` should be `toLowerCase()`, and `serializeJSON()` should be used on a DOM element, not on a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to convert the string to lower case is `toLowerCase`, not `toLowerCaser`, and there is no `serializeJSON` method on a string. You would use the `JSON.serialize` method:

```
var username = JSON.serialize($('#username').val().toLowerCase());
```

To find an error like that you should look in the error log in the browser, it should show you an error message saying that `toLowerCaser` is not a function. That should tell you that perhaps that's not what the method is called and look it up in the documentation (for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). When you fixed that you would get the same error for `serializeJSON`.

To use `console.log` to debug, you can split up the steps and progressively check the result. For example:

```
// check if jQuery found anything
console.log($('#username').length);
// check what the text is
console.log($('#username').val());
// check if toLowerCaser works
console.log($('#username').val().toLowerCaser());
// check if serializeJSON works
console.log($('#username').val().toLowerCaser().serializeJSON());
```

#### Edit:

When you have shown the HTML code also, I see that it doesn't contain any element with `id="username"`, so `$('#username')` will be an empty jQuery object.

If you try `console.log($('#username').length);` you will see that it writes out `0`.

Comment: that make more sense but even when i just write console.log ("test); from within the function i still don't see any log. Only when i do it above the fucntion does it work. Ill update my code to show all the HTML as well.

Comment: @user3413252: If you test the first `console.log` test from above, you will see that it will write out `0`. There is no element with `id="username"` in the page, so the jQuery object will be empty. When you use `val()` on it, it will return `null`, and you can't use `toLowerCase` on a null reference so you will get an error there. When you get an error the exection will stop, so the next line that writes to the log will not be executed.

Comment: am i supposed to see these errors in the console somewhere or are they not shown? Because when i run the program i see nothing in my console.

Comment: @user3413252: Yes, they should show up in the console, the same place where you see `console.log` messages.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the line you wrote above:

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'JSON.serialize($('#username').val().toLowerCase())')
(anonymous function)login.html:14
dispatchjquery.js:4597
handlejquery.js:4281

Comment: @user3413252: Yes, that is correct. As the jQuery call doesn't find an element, the `val()` call will return `undefined` (not `null` as I wrote before), so when you try to get `toLowerCase` that will also be `undefined`, and calling it will give that error message. If you try `console.log($('#username').length);` you will see that it writes out `0`.